# HTML Code doesnt display the intended result

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?preview.size=20" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <h1>Kalyan The Coder</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="TextBox1" placeholder="Enter your query">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="button">post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran this code and the Button doesn't show up next to the input box. Its under the text input box which is not the way it is supposed to work. Any ideas
I have the buttons inside the form and still no luck

Comment: any submit on a form do a page load, in your case this is a reLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used bootstrap classes but not linked/imported them into your html.
Add the following:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It should show up in the same line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?preview.size=20" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <h1>Kalyan The Coder</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-8">
            <input type="text" id="TextBox1" placeholder="Enter your query">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="button">post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are bootstrap classes. I am new at this. Html is what i like the most. But doesnt have enough resources and hence I rely on stack and other youtube videos for classes. Thanks. Kindly let me know what it is in layman terms. I really appreciate your response. :-)

Comment: @KalyanSundar [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/) is a css library. It helps in structuring & designing your html without writing any css. In this case you have used css classes like `col-xs-4` `conainer` `row` etc., which are defined in bootstrap but did not import the library. So the ui was breaking

Answer (score 0):

You put the two form elements in separate `div`s, which made them block elements. Just put them on one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?preview.size=20" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <h1>Kalyan The Coder</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="TextBox1" placeholder="Enter your query">
            <button type="submit" class="button">post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```